# Insert data into mysql using OOP PHP and PDO

Tags: php, oop, crud

I am new to PHP and trying to learn OOP PHP.

I am creating a registration form (a simple one) to learn OOP PHP, when I submit data the success message shows up but data is not inserted in data base.

Below is my code:

**connection.php**

```
<?php

class DBConnection extends PDO
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $host='mysql:host=localhost;dbname=OOP';
        $user='root';
        $password='';
        parent::__construct($host,$user,$password);
        $this->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        // always disable emulated prepared statement when using the MySQL driver
        $this->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);
    }
}

?>
```

**Index.php**

```
<?php
session_start();
/*include 'classes.php';
//$dbHandle = new DBConnection();
$ins=new basic_operation();
$ins->Insert_Data();*/



?>


    <div class="col-lg-12">

        <div class="col-lg-1"></div>

        <div class="col-lg-7">
            <form action="user_data.php" method="post" >
                <input type="text" name="username" id="username" class="form-control"><br>
                <input type="email" name="email" id="email" class="form-control"><br>
                <input type="password" name="password" class="form-control" id="password"><br>
                <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="submit">
            </form>
                    </div>

                </div>
<div>
    <?php if (isset($_SESSION['insert']))
    {
        echo $_SESSION['insert'];
        unset($_SESSION['insert']);
    }

    ?></div>

        </div>
    </div>
```

**User_data.php**

```
<?php
session_start();
include 'classes.php';

    $insert=new basic_operation();
    $usr=$insert->Insert_Data();
    //return $insert;
    $_SESSION['insert']='data inserted successfuly';
    header('location:index.php');

?>
```

**Classes.php**

```
<?php
include 'connection.php';

class basic_operation
{

    public function Insert_Data()
    {
        if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
            $user = $_POST['username'];
            $email = $_POST['email'];
            $pass = $_POST['password'];
            $smt = new DBConnection();
            $qry = $smt->prepare("insert into student(User_Name,Email,Password) VALUES ('" . $user . "','" . $email . "','" . $pass . "')");
            $qry->execute();

        }
    }
}
?>
```

If any one knows how to perform basic CRUD (insert, update, delete, select) operation in PHP using OOP PHP and PDO Then please provide the link, source, Example, so i can learn from it

I searched on the internet but bearly able to find the connection code...  Looking for a descriptive answer, as I think this question will also help a lot of people who try/want to learn OOP PHP.

Any help will appreciated.

Comment: The best place to start is of course [The PHP Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php)

Comment: You had the sense to set PDO to use `PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION` but you are not using `try/catch` blocks to catch any thrown exceptions and you are therefore not displaying and errors that happen

Comment: Have you written all the code yourself? If no, then I'd recommend start everything from scratch or you need to understand the structure of the code. In above code, inputs aren't bound and they are directly inserted (Risk of MySQL injection) as well as the `InsertData()` function is specific to a same type of data. If you wish, I'd rewrite a code in my own style.

Comment: This code is working fine here, Please check

Comment: The reason your query fails is the last part of my answer. You don't quote the reserved keyword `password` with backticks in your query.

Answer (score 0):

Use `try-catch` in your connection script to get errors.

```
try {
    $pdo = new PDO(
    'mysql:host=localhost;port=3306;dbname=your_db;charset=utf8mb4',
    'user',
    'password',
    array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES utf8mb4")
    );
    $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo 'Database connection has failed. Contact system administrator to resolve this issue!<br>';
    $e->getMessage();
    die();
}
```

Enable error reporting in php (add this on top of your php script).

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

Since you want to use prepared statements then you will have to bind your parameters in order to get escaped properly.

```
        $qry = $smt->prepare("INSERT INTO `student` (`User_Name`,`Email`,`Password`) 
                              VALUES (:user,:email,:pass);");
        $qry->bindParam(':user', $user, PDO::PARAM_STR, 255);
        $qry->bindParam(':email', $email, PDO::PARAM_STR, 255);
        $qry->bindParam(':pass', $pass, PDO::PARAM_STR, 255);
        $qry->execute();
```

> Prepared statements with bound parameters are not only more portable,
>   more convenient, immune to SQL injection, but are often much faster to
>   execute than interpolated queries, as both the server and client side
>   can cache a compiled form of the query.

**source:** Description of PDO::quote in [php.net](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.quote.php)

And last but not least... Always use backticks “`” in your MySQL queries to properly [quote](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/identifiers.html) MySQL [Keywords and Reserved Words](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/keywords.html#ftn.idm139768971836144) such as ***PASSWORD***. You use it in your query as a field but you don't quote it.

Answer (score 0):

Actually the code is working fine, when i try to run it directly using localhost without using phpstorm then it works.. mean the issue is in my IDE.

Thanks for your efforts.

Answer (score 0):

```
`if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
        $user = $_POST['username'];
        $email = $_POST['email'];
        $pass = $_POST['password'];
        $smt = new DBConnection();
        $qry = $smt->prepare("insert into student(User_Name,Email,Password) VALUES ('" . $user . "','" . $email . "','" . $pass . "')");
        $qry->execute();

    }`
```

Try this

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
        $user = $_POST['username'];
        $email = $_POST['email'];
        $pass = $_POST['password'];
        $smt = new DBConnection();
        $qry = $smt->prepare("INSERT INTO student(User_Name,Email,Password) VALUES (:user,:email,:pass)");
$qry->execute(array(':user'=>$user,':email'=>$email,':pass'=>$pass));

    }
```